# my async functions repeats itself for unlimited times

Tags: react-native, async-await

i am using async function to retrive the discounts from the API and then use that discount in the cart,
whenever the discounted cart function is called in the render method it start repeating it self , but whenver the calling is performed through the button on click event, it runs perfectly.

```
discountedCart = async (id, qty) => {
    console.log("Discounted Cart");
    const response = await fetch(
    
      "https://usautoparts-erp.azurewebsites.net/Api/Cart",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ products: [id] }),
      }
    );

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({
      DiscountData: data,
    });
    let D = "No discount";
    const discounts = data.filter((item) => item.quantity <= qty);
    console.log("selected");
    console.log(discounts);
    if (discounts[discounts.length - 1].amount != null) {
      D = discounts[discounts.length - 1].amount;
      console.log("Amount:" + D);
    } else if (discounts[0].percentage != null) {
      D = discounts[0].percentage;
      console.log("percentage:" + D);
    }
    console.log("Discount:" + D);
    this.setState({
      rough: D,
    });

    return D;
   
  };

render() {
   

    return (
   <>
        <Button title="Clear Cart" onPress={() => this.ClearCart()} />
       
        
        <FlatList
        
          data={this.state.p}renderItem={({ item }) => 

          {const a = this.discountedCart(item.id,item.Qty);
            return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 1 }}>
              <Text>{item.id}</Text>
             
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          }
          numColumns={1}
          
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
       
          
       
        />
     </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
{const a = this.discountedCart(item.id,item.Qty);
```

You fire discountedCart function that sets the state resulting in re-render.
When the component re-renders it calls the same function setting the state => re-rendering again.

Make sure you are not calling a function in your render method *which alters your component state* (or basically uses setstate).

You may want to fetch the data and calculate discounted cart on componentDidMount and then set the state, use that state property in your render method